# Using sanitize within a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper, sanitize

I'm trying to call `sanitize` within a controller. Here's what I tried:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
  # ...
end
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `white_list_sanitizer' for FooController:Class
```

I searched around and people recommended switching the include line to include `ActionView::Helpers`, but that results in this error:

```
undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass
```

What's the correct way to call `sanitize`? I'm using Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: To, for example, sanitize user input before passing it to RDiscount to generate HTML from Markdown content.

Answer (score 59):

you can use this `ActionController::Base.helpers` inside action method:

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize('<b>bold</b>')
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for the record (and google): this is the perfect solution to use sanitizer from a helper method that's called from a controller.

Comment: Great answer, still. Can also abbreviate to just `helpers.sanitize('<b>bold</b>')` for brevity.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 6:

To strip links (for example) from a text, just call:

```
...
Rails::Html::LinkSanitizer.new.sanitize("links here will be stripped")
...
```

see https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but I'm almost 100% certain it doesn't belong in the controller.

If you want to sanitize an attribute before you save it to the DB, do so in the model with a before save callback.

Otherwise, sanitize in the view template or view helper.

Comment: Chances are he was trying to render text using AJAX without using a view.

Comment: or writing an API where you need to sanitize the html