# Undefined method #sanitize for ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I just upgraded to Rails 5.1.1 and am receiving this error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `sanitize' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class):
```

The stack traces back to this code

```
like_search_term = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize("%#{escaped_search_term}%")
```

Has this method been removed or changed in the new Rails upgrade?

Comment: It seems that it does not work in model, but it did work in view, I tried it with Rails 4.2

Comment: You can check this answer it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077253/1770571

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it appears to be [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947).

> Sanitize was never part of the public API of the framework. As we didn't need it in the framework anymore, we removed. The recommended ways  to sanitize raw SQL for use in execute statements were the public API for that http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up going with 'ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote' as a drop-in replacement. That fixed my test suite. Anyone know of a better practice?

Comment: However when I try query_string = ActiveRecord::Sanitization.sanitize_sql(params[:q])

I am getting 

NoMethodError: undefined method `sanitize_sql' for ActiveRecord::Sanitization:Module

Comment: Maybe I understood the question wrong, but ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(params[:q]) is still working fine without any error.

Comment: @Surya: in what rails version?

Comment: rails version: 5.0.1

Comment: @Surya: it was removed later.

Comment: Then perhaps sanitize_sql were introduced in the later versions too. Thanks

Comment: The solution at the first link solved the problem for me: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947#issuecomment-310733481

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the sanitization methods if you use them within context of the model.  For example, you can add this to your model:

```
def self.where_ilike(search_terms)
  where('search_tokens ILIKE ?', "%#{sanitize_sql_like(search_terms)}%")
end
```